# Mapping project - I want to show KML files on a map and be able to sort them based on date, location etc

Tags: javascript, python, leaflet, folium

I am currently undertaking what might be an overly ambitious project for my skill level, but I think I could learn a lot form this exercise.

I work for an aerial surveying company and each time a project is flown, the LiDAR software creates a log file. From this log file, I have written a script that extracts the data and outputs a KML file with data such as flight line numbers, location, height etc.

What I now want to do is write a program that can upload these KML's to a database and show them in a window similar to Google Earth that the user can sort through the flight numbers, locations and dates etc. This would be an incredibly handy piece of software at work and a lot of people would use it, not to mention massive brownie points for my trying to secure a Jnr Dev position in the company going forward.

I know I could mostly use Google Earth to accomplish this task, but for me, it's kind of not the point.

So far, I have looked into Folium and LeafletJS.

https://leafletjs.com

https://pypi.org/project/folium/

Folium can manipulate data and Leaflet can present it, but I am not sure I have the best solution for the job and if it can do exactly what I need to. Especially considering that I only know a little Javascript. I am also not sure if Folium

Ideally, this app would be either a standalone piece of software, or something that my existing script writes to an online server and then can be opened and shown through a browser window. I am biting off more than I can chew with this, but I'm prepared for it to take a little time and be a good learning project. Preferably written in Python.

Any hints or suggestions to what packages I might use would be greatly appreciated. Or, if I am going about this in completely the wrong direction, please let me know.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

Here are a few elements that might be useful to you :

- leaflet can natively load [geojson](http://geojson.org/) files. So you could either convert the kml files to geojson using python, or use a [leaflet plugin](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html) (leaflet-omnivore for example) to read kml files with leaflet. As a first step, I would start with that : a web page that shows one of your flight path. The path data being just a geojson file that is loaded by your app.
- then if you want your app to filter flight paths on some criterias, and if you have many of those files, you're going to need a backend. That means a server, with a database, potentially with geo-capabilities (postGIS, mongoDB,... there are many) and a backend application. So your front app (with the js and leaflet) is going to send some requests to your server (send me the file for the flight XYZ please), the backend receives that request, performs a database query, get the file and send it back to the client. The client displays the data on the map.

If you want to write the backend in Python, you can have a look at frameworks like [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) or [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

That's a lot of tools, but if you start with the js + leaflet part, you will be happy to see a map quickly and will have something to show pretty soon. Then you can start having a look at the backend part. If you manage to get this project done...you definitely deserve that junior dev position.